# htaccess редирект с каталога

Tags: .htaccess

Всем привет! Подскажите как настроить редирект в .htaccess по следующему условию.

1. https://site.ru/shop/accessories/101/   ->  https://site.ru/shop/accessories/101/
2. https://site.ru/shop/accessories/  -> https://site.ru/
3. https://site.ru/shop/  -> https://site.ru/

То есть, нужно редиректить с каталога и подкаталога на главную, а если мы на детальной странице товара, то оставить без изменений. Подскажите как это сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Что касается пункта 1: я понимаю, что вы не хотите делать перенаправление, но хотите, чтобы такой URL пропускался бы без изменений. Так что к нему ничего не применяем - настройка внизу будет игнорировать. А вот к двум следующим правило будет применяться и выглядит оно так:

```
Redirect 301 /shop/ https://site.ru/
Redirect 301 /shop/accessories/ https://site.ru/
```

*Учитывая комментарии автора*

Попробуйте через rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^shop/accessories/$ https://site.ru/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^shop/$ https://site.ru/? [R=301,L]
```

Результаты:

Для /shop/

https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=52702422-00d5-43f8-a6c2-ada7fb65c137

Для /shop/accessories/

https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=8e2cf9f7-2ace-41a7-93a3-33a87cbaf5af

Для /shop/accessories/101/

https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=42454e8e-5cd6-4904-a877-e52d822485ea

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но это не подходит. При переходе на страницу /shop/accessories/101/ перенаправляет на /accessories/101/. Если же мы перейдем на страницу /shop/accessories/ то перенаправляет на /accessories/. Как я понимаю отрабатывает первое правило и для всех адресов, в которых видит /shop/. Нужно чтобы отрабатывало исключительно на /shop/accessories/ и /shop/

Comment: "При переходе на страницу /shop/accessories/101/ перенаправляет на /accessories/101" - нет такого правила в моем примере. У меня двестрочки и перенаправления там на https://site.ru/ только. У вас либо что-то есть еще в htacces, либо ваш браузер использует кешированноую информацию. Зайдите на https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/ и проверьте мое условие в онлайн-тестере.

Comment: Странно, у меня это никак не хочет работать. Кеш весь почистил, оставил только правило на /shop/accessories/ и при переходе на /shop/accessories/101/ перенаправляет на /101/

Comment: Я добавил ссылки на тестирование для каждого. Вы можете видеть, что перенаправление на https://site.ru/ срабатывет для двух первых, но не применятся к третьему.

Comment: Ну там я проверил, на тестах работает, а у меня почему то нет

Comment: Проверьте с терминала ```curl -I https://site.ru/shop/accessories/ -L``` и посмотрите в ответе цепочку перенаправлений. 

Ответ будет выглядеть как-то так:


HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Thu, 01 Sep 2022 18:33:20 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: https://site.ru/shop/accessories/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Thu, 01 Sep 2022 18:33:20 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: https://site.ru/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 01 Sep 2022 18:33:20 GMT
Server: Apache

Comment: Ваш домен публичный? Я могу сам проверить?

Comment: `Ну там я проверил, на тестах работает, а у меня почему то нет` для начала стоит убедиться что в вашей CMS нет собственного роутинга или есть но отключен. почти уверен дело в этом. насколько помню тот же php позволяет задавать собственный вариант роутинга прямо в php коде безо всяких .htaccess. +чем глубже в иерархии находится .htaccess тем выше его приоритет. т.е. если есть роутинг в /shop/.htaccess, роутинг заданный в корневом .ht может может игнорироваться. убедитесь что нет лишних .ht